# MySQL Execute Event On Time

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if you can trigger an event in MySQL 5.1.73 if a time matches the current time. For example, if I have 2 columns; "Number", "Time" and the "Time" matches the current time, then it would change the "Number" value to something else. Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: So, you want [events, like this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)?

Comment: Yea I think that might be it. On that site, if you scroll down a little there is an example "create event statement". Will this event automatically delete its self or will I have to include deleting its self in the event result

Comment: *Whether an event persists past the end of its schedule also depends on its `ON COMPLETION` clause, if it has one.* for a greater overview, you can [read here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) -- f.ex. you need to enable this feature, because it's disabled by default.

Comment: Ok thanks, I should be able to  find what i need now.

Comment: Hey i dont know how to mark this as answered so if you could tell me, that would be great. Thanks again.